# Plotting time vs duration in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot a time vs duration scatterplot in R but encountered problems which I am not sure how to solve or if the problem lies in my data.frame.

I've tried looking through other examples on this website and others but haven't found what I'm looking for.

My data.frames look like :

```
    dput(head(departure.time))
    structure(list(V1 = structure(c(35L, 36L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("0:00", 
    "0:30", "1:00", "1:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30", "12:00", 
    "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00", "15:30", 
    "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30", "19:00", 
    "19:30", "2:00", "2:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", 
    "22:00", "22:30", "23:00", "23:30", "9:00", "9:30"), class = "factor")), .Names =       "V1", row.names = c(NA, 
     6L), class = "data.frame")

    dput(head(travel.time))
    structure(list(V1 = c(490L, 492L, 485L, 486L, 483L, 488L)), .Names = "V1",     row.names = c(NA, 
    6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'm not sure why my travel.time is showing only 6 entries when it has 36 obs as does the departure.time frame

Additionally, the code i tried was

```
    plot(departure.time, travel.time, main="Variable Travel Time", xlab="Departure Time", ylab="Travel Time in Minutes", pch=19)
```

But i received the error

```
    Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :
```

'x' and 'y' lengths differ

Any advice?

Comment: It is only showing 6 entries because you used `dput(head(travel.time))`, which asks R for the first 6 rows of `travel.time`. Please edit your post & post the results of `dput(travel.time)` and `dput(departure.time)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your code to:

```
plot(departure.time$V1, travel.time$V1, main="Variable Travel Time", xlab="Departure Time", ylab="Travel Time in Minutes", pch=19)
```

`read.table` outputs a `data.frame` (see `help(read.table)`, section *value*), so you need to tell `plot` which column to use from each data frame.

If you want `departure.time` to be a vector and not a dataframe, you should use `scan` instead of `read.table`.